# Is it possible to cure gut worms in Rimworld?

Tags: rimworld

There's a bunch of new diseases in the latest rimworld alpha. Is it possible to cure gut worms?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes. There are two ways to do this.

Gut worms will eventually go away with repeated treatment. This requires a total of 300% treament quality. For example, 3 treatments of 100% quality, or 6 treatments of 50% quality.

Alternatively, you can amputate the colonist's stomach. This will remove the worms. A colonist can survive without a stomach, but they will eat extremely slowly as a result. You can't transplant stomachs but you can craft or buy a bionic replacement.

Comment: Will all the new diseases eventually go away like for instance "muscle parasites"?

Comment: @KitSunde As far as I know, this applies to all the new diseases. Both the repeated treatment and the amputation.

Comment: With the version 0.15.1284 you can't harvest stomach so amputating one from your colonist is not the best idea.